# update dojo grid

Tags: dojo, grid

i am really  new to Dojo Grid.

I just loaded the grid ,now i want to know that how can i do update,insert,delete operations.

i am using Codeigniter ,so i just want the values on ma controller.

Recently i used Sigma Grid & it is very simple to do things,

i checked the online documents & api reference ,but it couldn't helped me.

also there is no FUNCTIONAL EXAMPLES TO SAVE DATA on that GRID.

my grid only have 3 fileds id,name,country.
how i get these values back to server when i do update/insert/delete operations.

Please dont redirect me back to default online Documents. i need functional examples.

also i am newbie in javascript ,i already searched here alot for a good example,googled a lot.

Please help me to begin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of datastore are you using ? Because this operations highly depends on the datastore you are using.

Dojo Grid is datastore aware, so you just have to update the datastore, not the grid itself.